# Selecting rows based on a column value

Tags: pandas, slice

I have a data frame something like this

```
data = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
       'Doc':['Order','Order','Inv','Order','Order','Shp','Order', 'Order','Inv'],
       'Rep':[101,101,101,102,102,102,103,103,103]}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)


    Doc     ID  Rep
0   Order   1   101
1   Order   2   101
2   Inv     3   101
3   Order   4   102
4   Order   5   102
5   Shp     6   102
6   Order   7   103
7   Order   8   103
8   Inv     9   103
```

Now I want to select rows for Rep that have Doc type as Inv only.

I want a dataframe as

```
    Doc     ID  Rep
0   Order   1   101
1   Order   2   101
2   Inv     3   101
6   Order   7   103
7   Order   8   103
8   Inv     9   103
```

All reps will have Doc type Orders so I was trying to do something like this

```
frame[frame.Rep == frame.Rep[frame.Doc == 'Inv']]
```

but I get an error

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use twice [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - first get all `Rep` by condition and then all rows by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
a = frame.loc[frame['Doc'] == 'Inv', 'Rep']
print (a)
2    101
8    103
Name: Rep, dtype: int64

df = frame[frame['Rep'].isin(a)]
print (df)
     Doc  ID  Rep
0  Order   1  101
1  Order   2  101
2    Inv   3  101
6  Order   7  103
7  Order   8  103
8    Inv   9  103
```

Solution with [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
a = frame.query("Doc == 'Inv'")['Rep']
df = frame.query("Rep in @a")
print (df)
     Doc  ID  Rep
0  Order   1  101
1  Order   2  101
2    Inv   3  101
6  Order   7  103
7  Order   8  103
8    Inv   9  103
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = ['Order','Shp','Inv']
frame = pd.DataFrame({'Doc': np.random.choice(L, N,  p=[0.49, 0.5, 0.01]),
                     'ID':np.arange(1,N+1),
                     'Rep':np.random.randint(1000, size=N)})
print (frame.head())

     Doc  ID  Rep
0    Shp   1   95
1  Order   2  147
2  Order   3  282
3    Shp   4   82
4    Shp   5  746

In [204]: %timeit (frame.groupby('Rep').filter(lambda x: 'Inv' in x['Doc'].values))
1 loop, best of 3: 250 ms per loop

In [205]: %timeit (frame[frame['Rep'].isin(frame.loc[frame['Doc'] == 'Inv', 'Rep'])])
100 loops, best of 3: 17.3 ms per loop

In [206]: %%timeit
     ...: a = frame.query("Doc == 'Inv'")['Rep']
     ...: frame.query("Rep in @a")
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 14.5 ms per loop
```

EDIT:

Thank you [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45642845/selecting-rows-based-on-a-column-value/45642879?noredirect=1#comment78254218_45642879) for nice suggestion:

```
df = frame.query("Rep in %s" % frame.query("Doc == 'Inv'")['Rep'].tolist()) 
print (df)
     Doc  ID  Rep
0  Order   1  101
1  Order   2  101
2    Inv   3  101
6  Order   7  103
7  Order   8  103
8    Inv   9  103
```

Comment: This may not be readable but can be singular with `frame.query("Rep in %s" % frame.query("Doc == 'Inv'")['Rep'].tolist())`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


frame_Filtered=frame[frame['Doc'].str.contains('Inv|Order')]

print(frame_Filtered)
```

Output I got

```
     Doc  ID  Rep
     0  Order   1  101
     1  Order   2  101
     2    Inv   3  101
     3  Order   4  102
     4  Order   5  102
     6  Order   7  103
     7  Order   8  103
     8    Inv   9  103
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want Rep 102. I only want Rep that only have Inv along with Order.